# Visual Studio - how to attach debugger to restarted application?

Tags: debugging, winapi, visual-c++, visual-studio-debugging

I have an application in C++ developed in VS2010. This application has an ability to restart itself when needed (some changes that requires it to reboot). Now there's some bug that occurs only under certain circumstances on the beginning of the new instance after the restart. The problem is that I can't find out what it is, because the new instance does not have the debugger attached (VS debug mode ends with the initial instance closing). Any idea how to automatically attach a debugger to the new instance?

Thank you

Comment: I don't suppose a [DebugBreak()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679297(v=vs.85).aspx) in your reboot startup, then reattaching the debugger, is possible? Automatically is going to be non-trivial (if even possible, and i'd like to know if it is as well).

Comment: BebugBreak()? Never heard of it, OK thank's, I'll try and let you know.

Answer (score 7):

I "discovered" how this is done after getting infected with some malware that used the same technique to wrap all calls to anti-virus products to redirect them to it's own executable!

Summarising [the steps described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), it just involves some registry editing. FWIW, tools like `DebugDiag` also used to use this method to trap an application launch and activate the debugger:

To setup an application to launch the debugger automatically

1. Start the Registry Editor (regedit).
2. In the Registry Editor, open the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` folder.
3. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\image file execution options`.
4. In the **Image File Execution Options** folder, locate the name of the application you want to debug, such as *myapp.exe*. If you cannot find the application you want to debug:

   a. Right-click the **Image File Execution Options** folder, and on the shortcut menu, click **New Key**.
   b. Right-click the new key, and on the shortcut menu, click **Rename**.
   c. Edit the key name to the name of your application; *myapp.exe*, in this example.
5. Right-click the *myapp.exe* folder, and on the shortcut menu, click **New String Value**.
6. Right-click the new string value, and on the shortcut menu, click **Rename**.
7. Change the name to `debugger`.
8. Right-click the new string value, and on the shortcut menu, click **Modify**.

   The **Edit String** dialog box appears.
9. In the **Value data** box, type **vsjitdebugger.exe**.
10. Click **OK**.
11. From the **Registry** menu, click **Exit**.
12. The directory containing **vsjitdebugger.exe** must be in your system path. See the above link for the full instructions.

Now, use *any* method to start your application. Visual Studio will start and load the application in the debugger.

Comment: OK, it may take some time till I go threw it. Thanks a a lot.

Comment: No problem but don't forget to remove the registry entry when done because it will remember long after you've forgotten ;-)