# Unable to debug console application while attaching to command prompt

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++

I hardly use command prompt applications, so this is likely going to be a novice issue.

When trying to debug a VC++ console application, I am trying to attach process to the cmd where I am calling the exe of the application along with passing it the parameters.

The breakpoints are saying that this won't get hit because no symbols are loaded.  When this has happened in the past(in a vb.net application) it was due to either the configuration being set to Release build rather than Debug build or in the properties menu, the pdb file wasn't get created.

In this application, it is currently set to Debug build and I can see the .pdb file in the folder.  There is a lot of differences between a VC and VB application using visual studios so I am wondering if there is some small option that is not checked, or if I cannot simply attach to process then have the debugger pick it up when I call the exe from the command prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot attach to `cmd` and expect to debug a child of `cmd`. Simply set the program you wish to debug as the target in Visual Studio and let Visual Studio start it. If it really is a console application, a console will be automatically created. If you need to pass it command line parameters, Visual Studio has a box for that too.

The only case I can imagine where you might need to start the process from `cmd` would be if you need to pipe input into it. In this case, you can force the JIT debugger to run by modifying the Image File Execution Options as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16030317/2101267), but I would strongly recommend not doing this unless you really need it.